# Numpy concatenate over axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array, `arr`, which represents **n** permutations of **m** coordinates. With each permutation, I'm attempting to calculate the **total round trip distance** (the problem relates to the travelling salesperson problem). To do this, I've been concatenating the first coordinate of each permutation and then calculating the round trip distance using `np.linalg.norm`.

```
array([[[40, 30],
        [37, 52],
        [52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [20, 26]],

       [[52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [40, 30],
        [20, 26],
        [37, 52]]])
```

To get the round trip coordinate sequences, I have been using the following.

```
>>> np.array([np.concatenate((a, a[0, np.newaxis])) for a in arr])

array([[[40, 30],
        [37, 52],
        [52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [20, 26],
        [40, 30]], # First coordinate concatenated

       [[52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [40, 30],
        [20, 26],
        [37, 52],
        [52, 64]]]) # First coordinate concatenated
```

Is there builtin NumPy functionality to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[[40, 30],
        [37, 52],
        [52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [20, 26]],

       [[52, 64],
        [49, 49],
        [40, 30],
        [20, 26],
        [37, 52]]])
a = np.concatenate(a, axis=1)  # merge into single array
a = np.concatenate((a,a[0,np.newaxis])) # add ending coordinates
N=2  # replace with number of merged arrays
result = np.split(a,N, axis=1)  # list of arrays
```